# What is the replacement for RecyclerView's deprecrated setAdapter method?

Tags: android

I always use `setAdapter` class with the `ListView`. Now this method also available in the `RecyclerView`, but it's `deprecrated`.

What is the replacement for this `setAdapter` method?

Thanks for your help

Comment: deprecated? Since when?

Comment: are you sure it's deprecated? [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) doesn't say that.

Comment: in android dev docs, this method is not deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It's not deprecated.
[RecyclerView.setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter))

Answer (score 0):

In which Android API it is deprecated? I'm using it on Android API 22 and it is not deprecated .
It isn't also deprecated in documentation
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)